# How much of a large's creature's space must be above a pit before it falls?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Inspired by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26300/how-much-of-a-larges-creatures-space-must-be-above-a-pit-before-they-fall), I wondered how this works in 3.5 edition. I did not find it in the Falling section of the Environmental hazards glossary in the DM's guide, is it covered somewhere? Should I assume it to be the same as in the following edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure if it’s ever specifically addressed, but the 4e rule would work quite nicely in 3.5, and even in the absence of an explicit rule you could argue that the rules of 3.5 would work out the same: the creature isn’t able to fit all of its space on the grid because of the pit. It therefore must squeeze itself in the remaining squares.

Comment: I'm pretty sure KRyan is right about there being no RAW answer to this. Personally, as a DM, I would start penalizing the creature for lack of stable footing (penalty to attacks, weapon damage, rolls made to resist combat maneuvers, and anything else that seemed appropriate) as soon as 1 square of its space is over the pit, unless the pit is completely spanned by his space. I would have them topple in when they can no longer keep their center of gravity (abstracted as the center of their space) over their support base. Creature can then choose when to take squeeze penalty vs stability penalty.